# How to get same string value in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have got a excel document. I want to find same string values and copy another sheet. How to get  and copy values with excel?

[example document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5Nns.png)

For example:

I want to get all "name=John Doe" values and copy another sheet. I am using excel 2010.

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: You will want vba for this not formulas.  It would require many Array formulas ans after a time it will crash excel.

Comment: If this is just a one-time thing, filter the column for the text you're looking for, and then copy the resulting rows to the desired sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For x=1 to range("A1").end(xlDown).Row
  If Cells(x,1)="name=John Doe" Then
     Sheets(2).Cells(t+1,1)=Cells(x,1)
     t=t+1
  End If
Next
```